# Can't login to Google Apps cPanel with multiaccount

Tags: gmail, google-apps

I have multi-account login enabled for my Google Apps email and also my normal gmail address. When I go to https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/domain.com I get to pick what account to use. I click my Google Apps email and then I'm forwarded to the Google Accounts overview page...

How can I login to cPanel? I've tried in all kinds of ways, but always gets redirected to the Google Accounts overview page instead... I have to use another browser just to access cPanel, which is quite troublesome.

Comment: I've had this happen to me once in a while as well. The only fix I've been able to figure out is to sign out of all the accounts. Then it will usually behave for a while.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that this is quite an old query, but the CPanel did not used to support Multi-login.

These days it does though, so going to Admin.google.com should allow you to use multiple accounts.